# opening a new empty shiny ui through actionbutton

Tags: r, shiny

My objective is to create a ShinyApp that opens a new empty UI whenever user clicks on submitButton.

Currently this is my code below. If the user types something in the text box and press Submit. The app shows what the user typed in the main panel. However I dont want to see the text, instead when the user clicks on the submit button , it should  open a new empty UI.

```
ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("submitButton example"),
  fluidRow(
    column(3, wellPanel(

      textInput("text", "Text:", "text here"),
      submitButton("Submit")
    )),

           verbatimTextOutput("text")
    )
  )
)


server = function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(input$n))
  })

  output$text <- renderText({
    paste("Input text is:", input$text)
  })
}


shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Is this possible ? Any tips or pointers are appreciated.

Comment: I'm not 100% what you mean by 'empty ui', but here is an example how to create dynamic UIs http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/dynamic-ui.html

Comment: I am pretty sure, you don't want just empty pages, but some more difficult thing. Could you come up with some example what the new pages should contain and what information they share with the "parent"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is not yet very functional, but does what you asked for.

```
ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("submitButton example"),
  fluidRow(
    uiOutput("newWindowContent", style = "display: none;"),
    tags$script(HTML("
      $(document).ready(function() {
        if(window.location.hash != '') {
          $('div:not(#newWindowContent)').hide();
          $('#newWindowContent').show();
          $('#newWindowContent').appendTo('body');
        }
      })
    ")),
    a(href = "#NEW", target = "_blank",
      actionButton("Submit", "Submit")
    )
  ))
)


server = function(input, output) {

  output$newWindowContent <- renderUI({
    "Welcome to your new window!"
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

The app is created, such that the ui created in `newWindowContent` is displayed in the new window. Sadly, new windows are somewhat cut off from the parent page, such that there is no easy way to configure each page independently. At the moment, all show the same content. None have reactivity features. I guess there can be initial configurations, if one uses the window's hash. But this works only client sided.

Nevertheless, it's a good start!